# Show that a complex function is not complex differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, cauchy-riemann-equations

> Show that a complex function $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ with components $u(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
>  \frac{x^{3}-y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}&  &(x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 
>  0&  &(x,y)=(0,0) 
> \end{matrix}\right.$ and $v(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
>  \frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}&  &(x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 
>  0&  &(x,y)=(0,0) 
> \end{matrix}\right.$  is not complex differentiable.

At first I tried to see whether the Cauchy-Riemann equations were satisfied. But then I saw my notes and it says in this case, these components satisfy the Riemann-Cauchy equations but yet still $f(x,y)$ is not complex differentiable. (Honestly, I still don't understand this because I calculated $D_{1}u(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \frac{-(x^{3}-y^{3})(2x)+(x^{2}+y^{2})(3x^{2})}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}&  &(x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 
 0&  &(x,y)=(0,0) 
\end{matrix}\right.$ and $D_{2}v(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \frac{-(x^{3}-y^{3})(2y)+(x^{2}+y^{2})(3y^{2})}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}&  &(x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 
 0&  &(x,y)=(0,0) 
\end{matrix}\right.$ and I don't know how they are equal? But I didn't go into the algebraic details and left it)

Do I have to calculate the partial derivatives and make each variable approach $0$ or something? Any tips are appeciated!

Comment: Maybe you can check whether $f$ is continuous or not, if it's not continuous then $f$ cannot be complex-differentiable

Comment: @AleTolcachier Does that mean I show, say $v(x,y)$ has different limits when $y$ approaches $0$ from two different curves? I set $y=x$ and $y=-x$. This gives $v(x,y)=x$ and $v(x,y)=0$. Is this the idea?

Comment: Yes, but $x$ approaches 0 too so that curve doesn't work.

Comment: $f$ is continuous, that is easy to check, the problem is that $u,v$ are not differentiable at $(0,0)$. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $u,v$ to be differentiable (as maps $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$) in the ordinary sense in an open set, not just that the partials exist.

Take $u$ for example, let $(x(t),y(t)) = t(1,\alpha)$, then ${u(x(t),y(t)) - u(x(0),y(0)) \over t} = {1 - \alpha^3 \over 1+\alpha^2}$, so it is clear that the limit is different depending on $\alpha$. Hence $u$ is **not** $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $(0,0)$.

(Remember just because ${\partial u(x,y) \over \partial x}$ and ${\partial u(x,y) \over \partial y}$ exist does not mean that $u$ is differentiable. An an extreme
example, suppose $u$ is zero everywhere except on the $x,y$ axes where it has value one. Then the partials exist but $u$ is not even continuous.)