# Is $ f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} : z \rightarrow z|z| $ complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $ f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} : z \rightarrow z|z| $ complex differentiable?

I want to proof this according to the definition that something is differentiable if

$\lim_{z\rightarrow a} \frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}$ exist in $\mathbb{C}$.

I wanted to try looking if $z = x+yi$ and $c= a+bi$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\lim_{y\rightarrow b} \frac{f(z)-f(c)}{z-c}= \lim_{y\rightarrow b}\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(z)-f(c)}{z-c}$, but I immediately get stuck in the calculations. Can anybody give me a tip how to simplify this?

Comment: Break this up in terms of $x$ and $y$ and use the Cauchy-Riemann equations instead. They're a little more fool proof than the complex derivative approach.

Comment: @cameron Yes, I already saw that this was a frequent method, but we have to learn it without using them...

Comment: In $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(z+h)|z+h|-z|z|}{h}$, write $|z|=\sqrt{z\overline{z}}$, $|z+h|=\sqrt{(z+h)(\overline{z}+\overline{h})}$ and multiply and divide by $(z+h)\sqrt{(z+h)(\overline{z}+\overline{h})}+z\sqrt{z\overline{z}}$. You will get a rational function of terms that all have limits except for a $2z\overline{h}/h$, which converges only for $z=0$. Therefore, $z$ is differentiable at $z=0$ only.

Comment: **Warning** The Cauchy-Riemman equations alone don't prove complex differentiability. You also need to check that the function is differentiable at the point. There are examples of functions that satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations at a point and are not complex differentiable at that point.

Comment: Your difference quotient looks like $$\frac{z|z|-c|c|}{z-c} = \frac{z|z|-c|z|+c|z|-c|c|}{z-c} = \frac{(z-c)|z| + c(|z|-|c|)}{z-c} = |z| + c\frac{|z|-|c|}{z-c}.$$ I used a clever form of $0$ here to get something a bit more amenable to normal techniques. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3517401/917479) is an example of a function satisfying Cauchy-Riemann at a point and not being complex differentiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ were complex differentiable at $a\neq 0$. Then so would
$$ g(z) = z^{-1}f(z) = |z|, $$
which it is not, indeed it is real-valued.

Note however that $f$ *is* complex differentiable at $0$, with $f'(0)=0$.