# A doubt regarding complex differentiablity of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is to find points where the complex function$$f(z) =||z|^2-1|^2$$ is complex differentiable. My answer after taking partial derivative with respect to complex conjugate of z is given by $2z(z\overline{z}-1)$, which is zero if and only if either $z=0$ or $z$ is on unit circle. So points of complex differentiablity are origin and whole unit circle. But answer is given that there is only two points of differentiablity  which are $0$ and $1$. Please tell me where is mistake. Thank you.

Comment: What you did is correct. $0$ and $1$ are not the only points where the complex derivative exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is real, $f(z)=u(x,y)$. By the Cauchy Riemann conditions you need $\partial_x u=0$ and $\partial_y u=0$. But
$$
\partial_x u= 2(x^2+y^2-1)\cdot 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot 2x
$$
And a similar expression for $\partial_y u$. So your function is differentiable on the unit circle and at the origin.

Comment: Remember that Cauchy-Riemann equations alone tell you [only](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3517401/917479) points where it is *not* complex differentiable. To ensure that at those points there is complex derivative, you also need to show real differentiability.

Comment: This function is a polynomial so clearly differentiable as a function of two real variables. The CR equations are conditions to ensure (complex) differentiability. I see your point but differentiability is not an issue here

Comment: Yes no need to check extra conditions. Only CR-equations are sufficient in this case. Thank you.

Comment: @Ymylife What you are saying is incorrect. Checking real differentiability is part of the hypothesis of the theorem. Examples like the one I linked show that you cannot remove checking that condition, however simple to check.

Comment: I believe the OP understands this point. This is why he/she says “in this case”

Comment: @plop sir i want to say that as real and imaginary parts of function are polynomials in x and y so clearly have continuous partials derivatives, so no need to check that. Am I right now?

Comment: @Ymylife Yes, once all hypotheses are checked/justified, then the implication is correct.

Comment: @plop thank you...